# Default value when Cast() fails for smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to cast a `datetime` to a `smalldatetime` and when a row has a date value out-of-range for the `smalldatetime` type I want to set the date to a default value of the max date allowed and still do my comparison.

```
SELECT Sum(Case When Cast(shph.datetoship as smalldatetime) < @day1datetoship Then shpd.ordered Else 0 End) as TotDemandPast
FROM shipments shph
WHERE shph.pending = 1;
```

So when `shph.datetoship` is for instance `2080-01-11 00:00:00.000`,
I want it changed to `2079-06-06 00:00:00.000` and then compared to `@day1datetoship`.

Is there a simple and elegant way to do this?

**Update**:

After more testing, the two answers proved to give some issues.
Finally, ended up solving the problem by placing another `Case` statement within the `Cast`.

Final Code:

```
SELECT Sum(Case When Cast(Case WHEN shph.datetoship > '2079-06-06 00:00:00' THEN '2079-06-06 00:00:00' Else shph.datetoship END as smalldatetime) < @day1datetoship Then shpd.ordered Else 0 End) as TotDemandPast
FROM shipments shph
WHERE shph.pending = 1;
```

Comment: Why not convert everything to a `DateTime` and do your comparison then?

Comment: casting from datetime to smalldatetime will not have out-of-range issues, i am guessing you are casting from varchar to smalldatetime. And "I want it changed to 2079-06-06" is making no sens =/

Comment: Why not cast the variable to datetime instead?

Comment: This is part of a much larger query that was written and I have inherited and this seems to be most logical place for a solution to my issue.  @Ricardo the '2079-06-06' is the largest max value of smalldatetime type so if a datetime value is larger than that then there will be an out-of-range error.

Comment: @StevenB I see. I missed that. you are right, and the max val for datetime is 12/31/9999. ok, now it all make sense =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query which uses `Try_Parse` syntax. Note that this is used in newer versions of SQL server(2012 and above)

```
SELECT 
  Sum(
      Case 
      When ISNULL(Try_parse(shph.datetoship as smalldatetime),'2079-06-06') < @day1datetoship 
      Then shpd.ordered 
      Else 0 
      End
      ) as TotDemandPast
FROM shipments shph 
WHERE shph.pending = 1;
```

For lower versions of SQL server you can use following queries

```
SELECT 
  Sum(
      Case 
      When 
       ( 
         shph.datetoship >='1900-01-01' AND 
         shph.datetoship <='2079-06-06' AND 
         CAST(shph.datetoship as smalldatetime) < @day1datetoship 
       ) OR 
       ('2079-06-06' < @day1datetoship )
      Then shpd.ordered 
      Else 0 
      End
      ) as TotDemandPast
FROM shipments shph 
WHERE shph.pending = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to be working in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @shipments TABLE(
    datetoship DATETIME,
    pending BIT,
    ordered BIT
)

INSERT INTO @shipments SELECT '1899-01-01',1,1
INSERT INTO @shipments SELECT '1900-01-01',1,1
INSERT INTO @shipments SELECT '2079-06-06',1,1
INSERT INTO @shipments SELECT '2079-06-07',1,1

DECLARE @day1datetoship SMALLDATETIME='04/11/2016'

SELECT
    Sum(
        Case
            WHEN shph.datetoship>='1900-01-01' and shph.datetoship<='2079-06-06 23:59' THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN Cast(shph.datetoship as smalldatetime) < @day1datetoship then shph.ordered
                    Else 0
                END
            When '2079-06-06' < @day1datetoship Then shph.ordered
            Else 0
        End
    ) as TotDemandPast
FROM @shipments shph
WHERE shph.pending = 1;
```

Comment: This also worked but the selected answer just did it in fewer steps.  Thank you @Ghost